# Roll 2 dice 1000 times

Tags: c++, dice

My professor asked us to write a program that:

1. uses a loop to simulate the rolling of a pair of dice one thousand times(Here I think a for loop would be useful).
2. With each iteration, the loop needs to count the number of times each value from 2 to 12(Here I am thinking if/else statements would apply)
3. When the loop ends, must display the number of times each value(from 2 to 12) occurred.

He has the assignment structured like so:

He wants us to use a function that goes into the 1000-time for loop, that calls ANOTHER function TWO TIMES per function call(to simulate two dice being thrown).

Let me explain what I have managed to put down

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  RollingDice

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int roll();
int rollDice();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
    {

        rollDice(); //This is the function that is supposed to call the roll(); 
                    //function two times. This makes sense to me that TWO DICE 
                    //are being rolled 1000 times. 

    }

    int result; //These two statements was where I was just hoping for something 
                //to work. I put these variable statements outside of the for 
                //loop because I was thinking that the int rollDice(); function 
                //definition(below) wouldn't know how to use it otherwise. I 
                //know that doesn't make sense, but I just can't explain why. 

    result = rollDice();

}

int roll()
{ //This function was provided to us by my professor. 
    static bool randomInitialized = false;

    int points;

    if (!randomInitialized)
    {
        srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
        randomInitialized = true;

    }
    points = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    return points;
}

int rollDice()
{ //This I wrote myself. I'm imagining this is how you call a function twice. 
  //The return statement in this function was my attempt of returning the sum
  //of the values of the two dice.
    roll();
    roll();

    return result;
}
```

Besides this part of the program not working, the other issue I still have is determining a way to have a counter for each value that occurs(however, I am imagining that that part of the program belongs in the for loop. that's about all I know though.). I have thinking deeply about this program since yesterday. I came back to it today hoping a fresh mind would solve it, but I'm still struggling. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rather than all of that `randomInitialized` rigamarole, why not call `srand` on the first line of `main`?

Comment: The counter can be an array of int and just increment array[result]

Comment: tho random function is supposed to generate a random number, it does not produce a totally random number. you will see repeated patters if you do something like    cout<< rand()%6<< endl;   However since you are using ctime library, you could do srand(time(0)); to seed the function randomly EVERY single time you run the code.

Comment: biophaz3I haven't used arrays yet. Can you show me, or is there a way of doing this with if/else counters?

Comment: OK I just noticed while formatting the code that you had no hand in writing the `Roll` function. You can't fix it, but you should ask the instructor why they did the `randomInitialized` thing. There could be an interesting story in the answer.

Comment: You can do this with if/else, but you will end up with a bunch of variables like `count2` and `count3` and a bunch of if statements like `if(sum == 2) count2++; else if(sum == 3) count3++;`. In your `rollDice()` function, you can't just call `roll()` twice and expect `result` to magically become the sum of the two values. Remember that `roll()` returns the result of a single roll, and you need the sum of two rolls. Think about how you would implement that.

Comment: Addendum to @FeiXiang 's comment: Learn to use arrays. Ask the Professor if there are any restrictions against using an array. Follow the assignment rules and get a good grade, but know that no sane programmer would use an `if`/`else if` here. If arrays are disallowed, ask about `switch`/`case`. `if`/`else if`should be the last resort.

Comment: @user4581301 I would think it's just to keep all the code in one function. Easier for a student to copy/paste into their program to use. *shrug*

Comment: @RetiredNinja A reasonable, if boring, story. I'd also accept "Because proper use of `srand`/`rand` is a future lesson." I'd quite possibly praise "Because it's 2018 and `srand`/`rand` is stupid, so I'm going to teach the `<random>` library in another few weeks."

Comment: For additional learning and help, [Wolfram Dice](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dice.html) is a good reference.

Comment: @McMissile `srand(time(0));` does not "seed the function randomly". Multiple calls to `srand` will make things even worse: likely the entire `for` loop will run in a fraction of a second, so if you call `srand(time(0))` in between each `rand()` call, you could get the same result from `rand()` all 1000 times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `roll()` evaluates to a number. To add numbers, we use `+`. To return a value, we use `return`.

Putting that together, we get a simple function to sum two rolls

```
int rollDice() { return roll() + roll(); }
```

If you have a numbered sequence of things, and the numbers are both close together and start near 0, one of the standard library's [SequenceContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)s is an appropriate holder for the whole sequence.

Here the things are counts for a particular throw. We know up front exactly the available values (2 - 12 inclusive), so `std::array` is appropriate. Any integral value that can hold at least 1000 is appropriate for a count. I choose `std::size_t` here.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::size_t, 13> counts {};
```

This will give us 13 0s, starting at position 0

```
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
         ++counts[rollDice()];
```

We choose which number with rollDice, and use it to select a count to increment

```
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 2; i < 13; ++i)
    {
```

We can now loop over our results, displaying the counts

```
         std::cout << "The count for " << i << " is " << counts[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1- Using maps to count how many times each number from 2 to 12: ( most practical)

```
int sumOfDice;
map <int,int> diceOccurances;
for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++)
{ 
    sumOfDice=rollDice();
    diceOccurances[sumOfDice];
    // Here you are storing how many times each of the dice values occured. Here's 
    // how you access the map;
}
for (auto const& x : socks)
{
        cout <<" Dice Total Number: " << x.first ;
        cout <<" Dice Number of Occurances: "<< x.second<<endl;
}
int rollDice()
{ //This I wrote myself. I'm imagining this is how you call a function twice. 
  //The return statement in this function was my attempt of returning the sum
  //of the values of the two dice.
    int die1,die2;
    die1= roll();
    die2= roll();
    result = die1+die2;
    return result;
}
```

2- Using if/else ( or switch );

```
int two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten ,eleven ,twelve;
two=three=four=five=six=seven=eight=nine=ten=eleven=twelve=0;
for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++)
    { 
        if ( rollDice()==2) two++;
        if (rollDice()==3) three++;
        if (rollDice()==4) four++;
        // and so forth until twelve++;
    }
int rollDice()
    { //This I wrote myself. I'm imagining this is how you call a function twice. 
      //The return statement in this function was my attempt of returning the sum
      //of the values of the two dice.
        int die1,die2;
        die1= roll();
        die2= roll();
        result = die1+die2;
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this(needs some alteration to fit into the rest of your Proff's code)

```
int rollDice()

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  srand(time(0));// randomly seed every time you run the code
  int dice1;
  int dice2;
  int storageData[11];//stores the number of times the values from 2 to 12   appears;
  for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
  {
    dice1=rollDice();
    dice2=rollDice();
    int sum=dice1+dice2;
    storageData[sum-2]+=1;  // updates the number of times the sum has appeared.

  }
cout << "the value x has appeared "<< storageData[x-2] <<" times"<< endl; // change the value of x depending on which sum number you want.
}

int rollDice()
{
  int x=rand()%6+1;// rand()%6 produces a no. from 0-5. rand()%6+1 produces a number from 1-6.
  return x;
}
```

NOTE in the above code we subtract (-2) for every element cos the sum starts from 2 and not 0.